# webpack require relative image

Tags: javascript, webpack, image-loading, urlloader

I have two files:

- ./img/mypic.png
- ./js/help/targets/target.js

In target.js:

```
<img src={require("../../../img/target.png")} />
```

With webpack.config.js:

```
 14   module: {
 15     loaders: [
 16       { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'jsx-loader?harmony' },
 17       { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
 18       { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|woff)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192' },
```

Which compiles the image into `./[hash].png`.

Now, I use `react-router`, so I'm at `/help/targets/target` and webpack is giving the image this path `/help/targets/[hash].png` where hash is a sha1 sum. I would prefer if it gave it the path `/[hash].png`. Just

How do I make webpack understand that for this js file, the file path to the image is relative in the same way as in the browser?

Comment: Do you really have to use `require()` inside of image tag `src` attribute? Doesn't it look weird?

Comment: Yes, or you can split your `<img ` tag into its own stateless component if you wish.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The trick is to give webpack a config-hint on what to base its paths on:

Use:

```
"output": { "publicPath": "/" }
```

To tell webpack not to be relative.

Comment: bless you. Thanks