# Can not find local images

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, webpack

I have a project built in React and Django. I am also using Webpack to load the changes. I want to display images from the local drive.

The file from which I want to display the photos is in:

```
myProject/brandplug/static/app/photoGrid/SampleDisplay.jsx
```

The photos are located in:

```
myProject/brandplug/static/location_photos/
```

The `index.jsx` file is in:

```
myProject/brandplug/static/app/index.jsx
```

The `html` file within which React is rendered is in:

```
myProject/accounts/templates/index.html
```

So from `SampleDisplay.jsx` I tried importing the images like this:

```
const itemStyle = {
  backgroundImage: `{require("../location_photos/" + ${photoName})}`
};
```

And then:

```
<div style={itemStyle}>
</div>
```

Instead of `"../location_photos/"` I also tried using `"../../location_photos/"` and `"../../brandplug/static/location_photos/"`.

However, the images are still not loaded.

How can I load them?

Comment: you need require image before use it. in `webpack` you should require file and then use it, as I see you are trying require file dynamically by name., you need do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/6uLLus9v/1/

Comment: But I am requiring it, as shown above.

Comment: you can not do like you do. webpack needs require file before build process., and you can't load files dynamically

Comment: https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

You're just setting the *backgroundImage* to be a string, that happens to be the same sytax as *require*.

You could *require* the image and use that:

```
const itemStyle = {
    backgroundImage: {require(`../location_photos/${photoName}`)}
};
```

but I've never tried this. You may find [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30485183/webpack-require-relative-image) SO question useful.

I would suggest that you don't try to use webpack to load the image, but instead ask Django to serve it.

```
const itemStyle = {
    backgroundImage: `url("/static/location_photos/${photoName}")}`
};
```

which assumes you have set up your static files to be hosted at */static/*

Also, you were slightly mis-using backtick string templates, i.e., you don't need the *+*:

```
`{require("../location_photos/${photoName}")}`
```