# Image not displaying when server running (React/Webpack/Node)

Tags: html, reactjs, webpack

When I open my html in a browser, my image displays fine, but when I run the node server and try to view it at the port, the image is not loading.

The path is correct (it's working when I just view in a browser).

How can I display the image normally at the port?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a little broad, but I'm giving it a shot. You need to install different webpack loaders in order to render images to the webpage.

Image-webpack: https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader

You can configure css, raw, json, file loaders in `webpack.config.js`. Also you'll need to take care of relative paths in webpack, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30485183/webpack-require-relative-image).

Indeed, my answer is incomplete, but for brevity I have given you a direction to look into. Hope it helps! Good luck.

Comment: At least leave a comment before you down-vote my answer -_- So that I can improve my answers next time!